# Удалить строки из тхт, но оставить одну

Tags: c#

В предыдущих вопросах, я спрашивал про строки, сейчам появилась нужда удалить все строки, равны или нет, не важно, но чтобы оставить одну..

```
Пример такой:

p92u4h
pEWUHG
queehg
```

Результат должен быть таким:

```
p92u4h
```

Главная часть кода это `убрать все строки, кроме одной (первой)`, которую реализовать, мозгов не хватает

P.S. Или может быть через `Skip(1)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если ваша коллекция реализует интерфейс `IList` (например, массив или `List`), то вы можете просто обратиться по индексу:

```
Console.WriteLine(myList[0]);
```

Иначе можно воспользоваться операцией Linq `ElementAt`:

```
Console.WriteLine(myList.ElementAt(0));
```

В общем случае, если вам нужно вернуть несколько начальных элементов можно воспользоваться операцией Linq `Take`:

```
var newList = myList.Take(1);
```

Comment: Гут! Тогда такой вопрос: как прописать такое выражение: "вывести на экран строку, которая находится перед строкой, которая вывелась"...сформулировал так

Comment: @Quarsh781, вам дали ответ, нажмите, что вопрос решен, а дальше можете задать новый вопрос про то, как выводить так и так.

Comment: @Quarsh781, задайте отдельным вопросом. Здесь реализация может сильно зависеть от коллекции. Ну и непонятно что значит "вывелась" - вы не контролируете этот процесс?